# Can polymorph and true polymorph change a PC's race and sex?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

Can *polymorph* and *true polymorph* alter a PC's race and sex? If a PC can be altered in such a way, can the PC speak and use his or her hands?

Comment: Just to make sure I've understood correctly, you're asking if you can use these spells to change a PC's race and/or sex, without changing their form completely?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the question, after editing at least, is a valid one: the description of True Polymorph at least, contains guidelines for changing a target into the form of a creature that has a statistics block similar to that of a monster but not one similar to that of a PC; namely, there's a guideline for using the _target's_ level as a comparison to the new form's _challenge,_ but not vice versa. The hands/speech part of the question is clearly answered in the text of the spell, however.

Comment: Why are you concerned that changing race or sex would cause inability to speak or use hands?

Answer (score 10):

### Rules Stuff

Well, for starters, *polymorph* can only turn things into beasts. Which is to say, creatures with the beast type - so no humanoids.

As for *true polymorph*, well...technically, by the rules, you can only use *true polymorph* to turn a creature into a creature with a Challenge Rating.

> If
> you
> turn
> a
> creature
> into
> another
> kind
> of
> creature,
> the
> new
> form
> can
> be
> any
> kind
> you
> choose
> whose
> challenge
> rating
> is
> equal
> to
> or
> less
> than
> the
> target’s
> (or
> its
> level,
> if
> the
> target
> doesn’t
> have
> a
> challenge
> rating).

The target doesn't need a Challenge Rating, it can use its level - so it works on PCs. But the new form has to have a Challenge Rating, so you can't turn a PC into a PC, so to speak.

That means that, for example, turning your buddy the Human Fighter 20 into an Elf Fighter 20 isn't going to work. On the other hand, you could turn him into a Drow Elite Warrior (CR 5). So, changing a creature's race with *true polymorph* is possible, it's just not simple.

By the same token, you can't turn your buddy the Male Human Fighter 20 into a Female Human Fighter 20. However, (and this is why I picked drow), you could turn him into a Drow Priestess (CR 8). It's a little questionable whether this would actually change his gender, though.

> The
> target’s
> game
> statistics,
> including
> mental
> ability
> scores,
> are
> replaced
> by
> the
> statistics
> of
> the
> new
> form.
> It
> retains
> its
> alignment
> and
> personality.

Again, going by the rules, *true polymorph* replaces the game statistics of a creature with those of another creature. But there's no clear evidence that gender is a game statistic. The Monster Manual has a very long section on Statistics, and gender isn't mentioned anywhere.

Any transformation along these lines will allow the use of hands and speech.

> The
> creature
> is
> limited
> in
> the
> actions
> it
> can
> perform
> by
> the
> nature
> of
> its
> new
> form,
> and
> it
> can’t
> speak,
> cast
> spells,
> or
> take
> any
> other
> action
> that
> requires
> hands
> or
> speech,
> **unless
> its
> new
> form
> is
> capable
> of
> such
> actions.**

### Non-Rules Stuff

You may well have read all that and thought "That's stupid!" every step of the way. *True polymorph* is a 9th-level spell, up there with *wish* in terms of cosmos-altering power. It can turn a kraken into a crab, or a dragon into a dog.

That being the case, the easiest solution (as always) is to talk to your DM. If you say "Hey, can I use *true polymorph* to change race and/or gender?" then you'll get the answer that is true for **your** game.

Of course, if you are the DM, that doesn't help you all that much. If a player asks you this, and you're wondering what to say, well, it's up to you. I will warn you that allowing *true polymorph* to turn creatures into forms other than the ones with a CR and a statblock opens it up to some weird abuses and crazy shenanigans. So how you rule on this is up to you, but it might be worth having a think about how much you trust your players, and how okay you are with having this stuff in your game.

Comment: This. As a DM, I think a spell that changes a kraken into a crab can absolutely change your gender. Whether the caster gets to pick between genders is another matter. See https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64576/how-much-control-does-polymorph-true-polymorph-allow-over-aesthetics?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/05/25/would-true-polymorph-allow-someone-to-change-their-race/ theres a sage advice on the subject. Seems like it may have just been a bit of a slip in wording to me.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You should regive the argument made in that tweet. Also note that developer tweets are not official rulings (which Sage Advice is). Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: In addition to what the others said, Mike Mearls is not an authority on the rules, and the linked tweets in particular don't reference the rules at all - Mearls simply says "what he'd do" to handle the specified situation.

Comment: While not "official" it's still certainly a usable citation.  Do please edit in the information to your answer, though, as we prefer not to have link-only posts as links go dead...

Comment: To the flaggers - Mearls or Crawford tweets, while not "official rules" are perfectly legitimate cites in an answer that carry some weight.  "Not an answer" flags have been declined.