# What do multiple castings of Arcane Lock on a door actually do?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you cast *Arcane Lock* twice on a door, would the second spell take effect after the first one is suppressed?

I realise the **effects do not stack** but if two spells are active on a creature/object and one is suppressed the other is still active.

The way I see it is that if a door has two *Arcane Lock* spells cast on it, it would take two *Knock* spells to suppress it for 1 minute.

If a creature tried to pick a lock it would increase the difficulty by +10  (not +20), but would it need to roll twice to pick the lock?

As an alternative spell example, if a creature had *Bless* cast on it, the benefits would not stack, but both spells are active. If one caster loses concentration the effect of *Bless* would still be active.

Feel free to use other spell examples/scenarios in your answer, if you need. I am happy with any answers from published materials as well as Unearthed Arcana.

Comment: Related, at least in my opinion: [Can multiple casts of True Polymorph stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161088/can-multiple-casts-of-true-polymorph-stack/161379#161379)

Answer (score 7):

## It would only require 1 casting of Knock to open the door.

From the [*Knock*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/knock) spell:

> If you choose a target that is held shut with *arcane lock*, that spell is suppressed for 10 minutes during which time the target can be opened and shut normally.

From the [*Arcane Lock*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-lock) spell:

> Casting *knock* on the object suppresses arcane lock for 10 minutes.

Both of these spells describe the target of Knock being the object Arcane Lock was cast on, so according to the spell description of Arcane Lock, all instances would be suppressed for the full 10 minutes with only 1 casting of Knock.

Both instances of it check separately if the object has had Knock cast on it, so both will be suppressed as that check returns true for both.

In the case of dispelling Arcane Lock with the [*Dispel Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) spell (emphasis mine):

> **Any spell** of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. **For each spell** of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability.

The for each implies it can end multiple spells on a single target, so it would end all instances of Arcane Lock at once, so having more castings wouldn't help here (unless they were cast at 4th level, then there would be separate chanced of them being dispelled).