# What options do I have for changing my character's sex?

Tags: dnd-5e

In a campaign I'm playing, the rest of the party and I have a recurring need for drops of Royal Blood. (Nothing devious; it opens doors)

We have, collectively, decided that the best way to secure a source would be to seduce the prince and have a royal bastard (we have cohorts who will be responsible parents!) we can every-so-often return to for a few drops of blood.

The DM thought this was a "rad" plan, and we've got the green light to attempt this. But, we have one problem: Every single one of the PCs is male... which makes getting on with the Prince an impossibility.

My character is a Level 5 Warlock willing to "bite the bullet" and handle the seduction. Are there any spells that would allow him to swap his sex for the duration of the 9 months of pregnancy? Being able to swap back after the happy event would be ideal.

I'm looking for this route specifically because the group of us have decided that *the necessary hi-jinks make this the preferred route*, even if there is a more "optimal" one.  This is a game after all, and this is the route we want to go down in pursuit of fun!

Comment: You know your plan is convoluted when...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The only spell that should be able to do that is the level 9 True Polymorph.

According to the PHB (p.283):

> You transform the creature into a different creature, [...] If you
>   concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the transformation
>   becomes permanent.

According to the SRD (5.1, p. 188)

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops
>   to 0 hit points or dies. If you concentrate on this spell for the full
>   duration, the transformation lasts until it is dispelled.

Either way, I would say that getting pregnant while transformed is not outside the scope of a level 9 spell. If you want to be male again, another casting of the spell can change you back, or (according to the SRD) it can be dispelled. If your GM goes with the SRD, be careful not to walk into an Anti-magic field while pregnant, though...

Comment: [This Crawford tweet series may](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/01/can-permanent-magical-effects-be-dispelled/) help clarify, and [this Q&A](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64575/can-true-polymorph-be-dispelled-or-reversed).

Comment: "The only spell" excluding *wish* perhaps?

Comment: @THiebert *Wish* is an exception to *every* situation, though; You can mention it after any statement about any edition of D&D. It's generally not a useful exception to point out, though, because it's an option whose reliability depends on the GM's discretion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64793/discussion-on-answer-by-szega-what-options-do-i-have-for-changing-my-sex).

Comment: Baleful Polymorph should work too.

Comment: @Trish That is not a spell in 5e, to my knowledge. We do have *polymorph*, but that only lasts 1h.

Answer (score 37):

**There are no explicit sex-swapping spells written into 5e.** (But [@Szega's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/97595/34514) absolutely right about *true polymorph* being able to accomplish it. You should upvote that answer like I did!)

In early editions of D&D there were spells and items (cursed) which would play hijinks with a character's gender or sex. (See, for example, the *girdle of femininity/masculinity* (DMG1e p.145)). These editions also capped a female PC's stats lower than a male's, for reasons that were self-evident, at least to that author.

Contrast that mindset with the statement on sex in the 5e PHB:

> You can play a male or female character without any special benefits or hindrances. Think about how your character does or does not conform to the broader culture's expectations of sex, gender, and sexual behavior. 
>   [...]
>   You don't need to be confined to binary notions of sex and gender. [...] Likewise, your character's sexual orientation is for you to decide. (PHB p.121)

Without getting into broader *social* views on gender and sex, I think it's easy to say that the *game*'s views on gender and sex have changed remarkably through editions, and this is why you do not find sex-assigning items/spells anymore.

---

So what do you do? You and your GM work up a quest/adventure which will help you find this item or spell--which might exist in *your* setting--or you make friends with a willing female co-conspirator. Or you *true polymorph*.

Answer (score 28):

An alternative solution to True Polymorph with a much lower spell level is **Reincarnate.**

This method will likely be much less consistent than some of the other suggestions, and does incur a somewhat considerable cost in components. It is much more accessible as a level 5 spell, and it does enable the change back to being male, though perhaps not exactly the same male.

It may also be somewhat less pleasant for the warlock, who would need to be willing to die repeatedly until the resulting body is capable of both bearing the prince's child and seducing him. You did say your party was on-board for hi-jinks.

Answer (score 14):

### Depending on your DM's ruling, a high level cleric can help.

The cleric class skill Divine Intervention may be able to help you, or may not. That will depend on how your DM wants to play it.

Step 1.  Find a level 10 (or higher) cleric (most likely an NPC).
Step 2.  Persuade or pay the cleric to attempt Divine Intervention to change the Warlock's sex.  It's not a sure thing, but it's perhaps worth a try.  The key in terms of role playing is to convince the cleric that this is a dire necessity.  Where's that party *face*?  Game on! :-)

> **Divine Intervention**
>   Beginning at 10th level, you can call on your
>   deity to intervene on your behalf when your need is great. Imploring
>   your deity’s aid requires you to use your action. Describe the
>   assistance you seek, and roll percentile dice.  If you roll a number
>   equal to or lower than your cleric level, your deity  intervenes. The
>   GM chooses the nature of the intervention; the effect of any cleric
>   spell or cleric domain spell would be appropriate. (SRD V5.1 p. 17; Basic Rules p. 23; PHB p. 59)

The intervention is not explicitly limited to a cleric spell or domain spell ... that's up to the DM.  What a cleric will charge you for this service, or demand from you in order to attempt this intervention, is probably a whole different story arc/quest in itself ... again, if you can persuade the NPC cleric to even do this.

> At 20th level, your call for intervention succeeds automatically, no roll required.

Whether or not a 20th level cleric exists in your world, or would be willing to do this is all in the hands of the DM.

Based on the criterion for "being able to change back" one then must approach this NPC cleric (after the bouncing baby girl or boy has joined the living) for why it is in the cleric's / deity's interest to revert to former sex.

Some great RP opportunities abound, and likewise more story hooks, payment for services, etc.  Speaking of RP, the clerical sort most likely to go for this is probably one with a Trickery domain per the suggestion @Eidolon108 in a comment... though any cleric/deity might see this opportunity to support their aims/agenda.  Once again, get that party *face* to get to work. :-)

---

Of course, if you are going to this much trouble, you may be able to hire a high level Wizard to cast a *wish* spell ... at your level those might be hard to come by.

Comment: Perhaps a god in the trickery domain?

Comment: @Eidolon108 Depends on what deities are active in the DM's campaign, but I like your suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

### Be an Elf

In Chapter 2 of *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*, we have the **Blessed of Corellon**:

> [...] The rarest of these blessed elves can change their sex whenever they finish a long rest — a miracle celebrated by elves of all sorts except drow. (The DM decides whether an elf can manifest this miracle.) [...]

Of course, as a blessing from a god, he may not be willing to allow it to manifest for such mortal hijinks.

### Visit [Undermountain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/wdotmm)

...or some other place you can get your hands on a *[Circlet of Human Perfection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/circlet-of-human-perfection)* (Wondrous, Uncommon, Requires attunement by a humanoid), which:

> The circlet transforms its attuned wearer into an attractive human of average height and weight. The circlet chooses the physical characteristics of the form, such as age, gender, skin color, hair color, and voice. Except for size, the wearer’s statistics and racial traits don’t change, nor do items worn or carried by the wearer. Removing the circlet ends the effect.

The fact that wearer's size changes is a clear indication that the circlet makes an physical transformation, rather than just an illusion. Either way, the resulting body is attractive, so that should make seducing the prince easier.

One wrinkle comes in the source of the circlet's choices being undefined. If it always makes the same choice for the same user, you may have to pass it around and hope somebody becomes female. It could change each time it is put on, or it could change each time it is attuned (so unattuning and reattuning would cause a new set of parameters to be selected). A little experimentation should determine how it works in your DM's mind, and how critical it is to stay on the whole length of the pregnancy.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple spells that can change a character's sex.  I'd speculate that the lowest-level one is *alter self*.  It's pretty clear that the spell can make you look like the sex of your choice.  It's not clear how deep the changes go, but if this spell's "aquatic adaptation" form can give you gills instead of lungs, then the "change appearance" form should be able to replace whatever other organs you need replaced.

The problem is that *alter self* only lasts for an hour.  Potentially you could cast it several times in one night if you wanted more time with the prince, but you won't be able to maintain it while you're sleeping.  (Also, er, you have to concentrate to maintain the spell, which might be difficult given your plans for it.  Also it's not a warlock spell.)

There are very few spells that will last for the full nine-month duration you need.  If you want to do this Rules As Written, the obvious path is to go with *true polymorph*, which means either you need to be level 17 or you need to call in a favor from someone *very* powerful.  You could also get this on your own at level 15 if you're willing to spend invocation slots on *aspect of the moon* and *master of myriad forms*.  (thanks to AntiDrondert for suggestion)

Given that your DM thinks this is funny, the actual way to do this is to tell your DM you're looking for sex-changing magic.  Your DM will homebrew something for you, and will make up an interesting price to pay for it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64794/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-b-what-options-do-i-have-for-changing-my-sex).

Comment: *Alter Self* can be upcast using two of the warlock invocations: *Aspect of the Moon* (this negates need in sleep) and *Master of Myriad Forms* (which allows casting of *Alter Self* at will).

Answer (score 4):

Back in the 1970s, when D&D was a game that people modified a *lot*, there was a ["Houri" character class](http://www.romfan.uk/frpg/dnd/magical/houri.htm). They're a very specialised kind of magic-user dealing with charming and seduction, and they have a fifth level spell that changes sex. If your DM wants this kind of hijinks in a game, they might appeal to him.

Answer (score 2):

### Look under a lost and lonely hill

First edition, of course, had the *girdle of masculinity / femininity* which changed one's sex.  That magic item hasn't made it into 5e.

However, a classic 1e module with a sex-change 'curse' has been updated in a 5e adventure product.  One of the chapters in *Tales of the Yawning Portal* (p. 219) contains a setting wherein there is an...

> **Archway**. Just as in other locations around the tomb, the mists that obscure the archway can't be penetrated with any sort of vision or magic. (If a character moves close to the archway and asks about it, explain that none of the stones of the arch glow.) The skeleton. of course, misleads the party, for any character passing through the portal will enter a 10-foot-by-10-foot room where their sex and alignment are reversed by a powerful magic. Exiting the room and reentering the archway will restore original alignment, but also deals 3 (ld6) psychic damage.

Comment: Cute but I don't see how this could be used as a solution. It sounds like the sex change is specific to the room as such the prince wouldn't be able to enter as a male and the warlock couldn't leave as a female. Also spending 9 months in a room isn't ideal (2020 wasn't that long ago)

Comment: @SkySpiral7 The archway leads to an alcove off of a larger room.  One needn't _remain_ in the room for nine months; passing into the smaller room through the archway 'reverses' sex and alignment, but exiting the same archway has _no effect_.  The sex-change effect is permanent, it is not specific to the room.  Thus the warlock would enter, have his sex changed, and exit as a female of opposite alignment.  If the alignment was an issue, she could enter again to re-reverse the alignment but leave her new sex unchanged, and then leave again, presumably to seek out the prince.

Comment: Ah "Exiting the room and reentering" you are correct. I missed that it triggers on entering but not exiting. And the damage is pretty minor even for a low level character.

Answer (score 1):

[Reincarnate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reincarnate) may alter your characters sex and will alter your characters look. You will never be able to go back to the previous character though without True Polymorph. This might have more negative implications than positive ones for you. However it's a really cool role-play spell.

Comment: Technically, Reincarnate does NOT change gender - just race. Allowing Gender with Race probably isn't a big deal, but RAW it's just a racial change.

Comment: @NautArch Nothing says it's just a racial change though. "The magic fashions a new body for the creature to inhabit, which likely causes the creature's race to change." The new body can be totally different proportions (respective to their species) -- why not physical sex? The suggestion it also likely changes race doesn't mean the spell only ever changes race. (That said, I'm adjusting it to "may" rather than "will" -- there's no guarantee Reincarnate does anything except, statistically, make you look different and almost certainly change your race.)

Comment: @doppelgreener The language is probably loose enough to allow and it's not really that much of a big deal. But "It retains the capabilities it had in its original form, except it exchanges its original race for the new one and changes its racial traits accordingly." does some fairly clear that race and racial traits are what change. Allowing gender change goes above that, but given there is no mechanical difference (other than the obvious), it's an easy give.