# Does a Clone spell work on a (True) Polymorphed creature? If so, to what effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

The spell *true polymorph* ends when dispelled - even when the creature has been in their 'new' shape for hundreds of years. According to the *Clone* spell, any such polymorphed creature should still be able to use their (transformed) flesh as a component for this spell. If so, any *Clone* should grow as the spell suggests, as their *present* form / in four months.

Assume thereafter: the host creature goes to zero hit points. Thus the *True Polymorph* ends and they revert to their origin-creature (ibid). If this original-creature then dies, can their soul claim the *Clone* that they made whilst polymorphed?

*Simple example:* an orc is *true polymorphed* into a dragon. Dragon *clones* itself. Dragon-form 'dies' / reduced to zero & it turns back into orc. Orc then dies. Can this orc-soul (re) claim the *clone*-dragon body?

Comment: I've tried to clarify what you mean by your question. Please check to make sure my summary is correct.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, it works

However, how it works differs between the spells.

### Polymorph

> This spell transforms a creature with at least 1 hit point that you can see within range into a **new form**.

This is the *same* creature. *Clone* "grows an inert duplicate of a living creature" so the clone you grow will be in its original, not transformed form. If the creature dies, its soul occupies the clone irrespective of the form it was in when it died.

### True Polymorph

> You transform the creature into a **different creature** ...

*Clone* will grow a duplicate of this *different* creature. If the *different* creature dies, its soul will move to the clone. If this *different* creature returns to the *original* creature then if it dies the clone won't work since the clone is not of the *original* creature.

Comment: Just an FYI, [True Polymorph *can* be dispelled](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64575/14878).

Comment: Interesting!  Best make sure you die on your own terms if you're *True Polymorph*ed, then XD If you *disintegrate* during your or an ally's turn you can go to 0 hp, die, and then revert to your original form versus going to 0 hp, reverting to true form, and then dying if it's the turn of an enemy who knows about your cloning plans.

Comment: This answers the question very well. So *Truly Polymorphed* creatures could theoretically make a copy of themselves that cannot be dispelled. Thanks, this was what i was wondering.