# Can killing the spellcaster undo a 'permanent' True Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, character-death, spellcasting

So I have a character (E) that, Many years ago, was True Polymorphed into an elf so his also-elven spouse (N) wouldn't outlive him so drastically. The result ended in E being roughly thirty years older than A to compensate for what we labelled as the difference between Elf Years and normal lifespan years.

Things happened, and due to time screw ups in the Feywild, A is now much older than E. If A dies before E, would it dispel True Polymorph and also leave me with a dead character?

Comment: Do you have the original printing of the PHB? There was a change in one of the errata that had an impact on the "permanent" nature of TP.  I have the original printing.

Comment: In this question, who is A? I'm inclined to lean toward A being the spellcaster, but it is unclear as it it currently written.

Comment: Very related: [Can True Polymorph be dispelled or reversed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64575)

Comment: Also related: [What is the meaning of 'permanent' in description of True Polymorph?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59857/what-is-the-meaning-of-permanent-in-description-of-true-polymorph)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No, killing the caster doesn't undo the change.

An unofficial tweet from Jeremy Crawford and changes to the spell as of 2015 confirm that it "lasts until dispelled". So killing the spellcaster would have no effect.

The description of [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) now states:

> Choose one creature or nonmagical object that you can see within range. You transform the creature into a different creature, the creature into an object, or the object into a creature (the object must be neither worn nor carried by another creature). The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies. **If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the spell lasts until it is dispelled.**

[A September 2015 tweet (albeit no longer official) from rules designer Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/642537146541174784) states:

> If the effect of a spell becomes permanent, it can be dispelled, unless its description says otherwise.

The way to end *true polymorph* is to dispel the spell somehow; killing the caster does not end the spell effect.