# Where is the cost for adamantine and cold forged iron weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

I've been up and down the indexes but I can't seem to find this. There are monsters that are vulnerable to adamantine, silver, and I think cold forged iron, but I can only find rules for the creation of silvered weapons (add 100 gp to the cost).

What is the cost of an adamantine weapon?

What is the cost of a cold forged iron weapon (or did I just make that up)?

I have the DMG, the PHP, the MM, and Princes of the Apocalypse - are the rules for this in any of those books and I have just missed it?

Comment: Answer may be provided in http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68180/how-can-one-obtain-an-adamantine-weapon

Comment: You have the answer to silver, adamantine has been asked and answered, and there is no cold anything iron in this edition. Voting to close.

Comment: I beg to differ that this is a duplicate question. The other question is HOW to get one in game, this is about where the rules talk about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't missed anything.

- The only mention in the rules about adamantine weapons is that certain creatures are vulnerable to them, and that drow elf NPCs are equipped with them.  There are no prices or magic item listings for them.  See also: [How can one obtain an adamantine weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68180/how-can-one-obtain-an-adamantine-weapon)
- Vulnerability to cold iron does not occur in this edition.  (Yes, you *did* just make that up!)