# Does coating your armor in silver add any effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, special-materials

Similar to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131089/functions-of-special-materials), I am curious about the effects of adding silver to your armor. Though [adamantine armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/adamantine-armor) (being the other enhancement able to be added to weapons/armor) has a specified effect (under magical item), I have found no entry as to what effects adding silver to your armor would give.

To add a bit more details, XGE says that adamantine weapons render each successful hit into a critical one. Likewise, Adamantine armor renders critical hits into normal ones. So I have it stuck in my head that since silver makes the weapon act as a magical weapon, then wouldn't silver armor give resistance to magical attacks? (such as elemental attacks)?

**Is there any effects added to armor that has been silvered?**

Comment: If you have more details relevant to the question please edit them into the question. Don't leave it as a comment. Also, where are you getting the idea that "silver makes the weapon act as a magical weapon"?

Comment: I was trying to avoid sounding like I wanted people to agree with my argument and stay on topic. As for silver making the weapon magical, it was my understanding since "Some monsters that have immunity or resistance to nonmagical weapons are susceptible to silver" So I know it's not actual magic, but my understanding is that it's magic adjacent.

Comment: XGtE says that successful attacks against objects with adamantine weapons are crits, not just any successful attack. Otherwise every single adventurer would have an adamantine weapon once they could afford one. :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are somewhat mistaken about [Silvered Weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#SilveredWeapons):

> Some monsters that have immunity or resistance to nonmagical weapons are susceptible to silver weapons, so cautious adventurers invest extra coin to plate their weapons with silver. You can silver a single weapon or ten pieces of ammunition for 100 gp. This cost represents not only the price of the silver, but the time and expertise needed to add silver to the weapon without making it less effective.

Werewolves and fiends are resistant to non-magical weapon attacks that aren’t silvered. There may be more creatures that are weak to silver but those are two examples.  Silver-coated weapons are not considered magical; it’s just that the creature they are hitting is weak against them.

However, you might be able to do this using the barbarian's [Path of the Battlerager](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheBattlerager) (SCAG, p. 121), though it's normally restricted in the Forgotten Realms only to dwarves.

Battleragers gain the ability to use spiked armor, described in a sidebar on the same page, as a weapon. The 3rd-level Battlerager Armor feature lets them use a bonus action while raging to attack with their spikes, and automatically do damage when grappling creatures.

And at 14th level, Battleragers get the Spiked Retribution feature:

> Starting at 14th level, when a creature within 5 feet of you hits you with a melee attack, the attacker takes 3 piercing damage if you are raging, aren’t incapacitated, and are wearing spiked armor.

So if your DM allowed you to either plate your spikes or make them entirely out of silver, you could in fact hurt a Werewolf or Fiend with your armor. I would imagine the cost to coat or make the spikes silver would be very high.

So if you happen to be a Dwarf Barbarian Battlerager in a campaign that is heavy in Werewolves or Fiends, and you have a lot of gold, it would be in your best interest to plate your spikes with silver. Actually, it sounds like a lot of fun.

Comment: Hmmm, given that, what about when a Werewolf takes a swipe at your character? would the silver coating on the armor not cause damage?

Comment: Silvered weapons are not considered magical whether or not other creatures are affected by it. It's just that some creatures are resistant/immune to all nonmagical weapons *except* silvered ones - silver still doesn't make them magical.

Answer (score 14):

#### Its gauntlets could be used as silvered weapons.

However, there's no special effect official listed in D&D 5th edition for silvered armor.

However, certain armor types, such as scale mail, come with gauntlets, which could be used to make a silvered unarmed attack against creatures who are vulnerable to silver weapons. This is usually an inferior option to a dedicated silvered weapon. Likewise, you can use a headbutt as an unarmed strike, in which case a silvered helmet may be useful.

According to DMG p.142, items crafted by the fey glow in the moonlight, shedding dim light in a 5 ft. radius. Such an item is also crafted from silver or mithral instead of iron or steel. This isn't true of silvered armor in general, but may be true of fey-crafted silvered armor which you find.

It may also have ornamental value, if it is inlaid with silver filigree (again, DMG p.142). This may give it cultural significance, if it was created in honor of some event. This may gain you some respect in certain circles.

Silver plating may make it more valuable. Consider that as per DMG p. 135, a silver plated steel longsword with jet set in its hilt is worth 750 gp as an art object, so a similarly fine suit of armor may be worth considerably more than a normal suit.

Comment: You don't need the silver if you are making an unarmed strike. The creatures that where silver is relevant are only resistant/immune to "Bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage From nonmagical **weapons** that aren't silvered". Unarmed strikes are [explicitly not weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks), so they already bypass that resistance: "Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons)"

Comment: Also, if you think your DM might rule against RAW and say unarmed strikes don't bypass immunity, or even if your strength modifier is negative (meaning unarmed strikes don't deal damage), lit torches also work as an improvised weapon dealing 1 fire damage.

Answer (score -1):

Silvering your thunder gauntlets as an armorer artificer could be a last resort to make it eligible for the official version of booming blade and green flame blade requiring a weapon worth at least 1 sp if your DM is strict enough on RAW, since their cost is officially undefined.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. You should support your answer with references to the rules if possible.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of undefined value by RAW — it is a misreading representation of [how the armorer works](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/187996/44723) in regards to the green flame blade, but if your DM follows that incoherent logic - which some DMs do, then trying to make this argument seems valuable.