# What keeps players from creating all legendary items imaginable using True Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, polymorph

So, True Polymorph can be used to turn creatures into objects, like lumps of [adamantine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50558/can-i-true-polymorph-a-goblin-into-adamantine-and-then-forge-him-into-a-sword).

> **Creature into Object**: If you turn a creature into an object, it transforms along with whatever it is wearing and carrying into that form. The creature's Statistics become those of the object, and the creature has no memory of time spent in this form, after the spell ends and it returns to its normal form.

So, **what keeps players from reaching level 17 and holding back for a month to turn a bunch of fish into [Vorpal weapons](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Items:Vorpal%20Greatsword#h-Vorpal%20Greatsword), [Belts of Giant Strength](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Belt%20of%20Giant%20Strength#h-Belt%20of%20Giant%20Strength), [Armor of Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/armor-of-invulnerability), [etc](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-rarity=5&filter-rarity=7&filter-requires-attunement=&filter-effect-type=&filter-effect-subtype=&filter-has-charges=)**? Items are, as far as I understand, objects.

I had the notion that [Wish](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wish#content) was on another league, but other level 9 spells would only *break* combat for a few rounds. True Polymorph seems to *stack* its effects to the point where the party gets it and, after a month, has doubled its power, both in and out of combat.

Comment: If that's the kind of campaign a DM likes running, is that a problem?

Comment: Well, even if the DM allows this, he might just be waiting to use a well placed antimagic field at the right inopportune moment...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no rules-as-written restriction to what items True Polymorph can create. However, Jeremy Crawford points out in his [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/910278122414653440?ref_src=twcamp%5Eshare%7Ctwsrc%5Em5%7Ctwgr%5Eemail%7Ctwcon%5E7046%7Ctwterm%5E1) that it isn't the intended behavior of the spell:

> True polymorph is not intended to make magic items.

It is fully up the GM or group to determine whether to observe this restriction, and whichever choice is better depends on the varying tastes on balance versus powertripping in high-level play.

Comment: Then the answer is *Absent a DM and future errata, only authorial intent*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yup. The value of authorial intent values from table-to-table, of course.